# How do I specify a buildSelectorParam in a DSL job parameters block?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I'm converting a manually constructed job to DSL to generate the job.

Here's the type of parameter I want:

[image: Interactive job editor parameter config]

How to I specify that in a parameters section?

eg: something like

```
  job('job-name') {
   ...
  parameters {
    buildSelectorParam, 'sgp_build_app_job_id' SpecificBuildSelector()
  }
```

Such that I can reference it using:

```
  steps {
    copyArtifacts('checkout_scripts_job') {
      buildSelector {
        buildParameter('checkout_scripts_job_id')
      }
    }
  }
```

What's the syntactical magic to construct a BuildSelectorParam in the param {} block?

Answer (score 1):

I spent awhile trying to figure this out, and it seems to be the following:

Parameter Definition:

```
buildSelectorParam('sdk_to_package') {
  defaultBuildSelector {
    latestSaved()
  }
  description('Select the build to package for Developer Console')
}
```

That being said, it won't render via Blue Ocean, and the default Job DSL documentation is wrong (as of right now).

Once you install Copy Artifacts, you'll see there are two references, the "dynamic" reference seems to be correct, and works when formatted like this:

```
copyArtifacts (
  filter: 'ios-framework.zip, unity-sdk.zip', 
  projectName: '/mobile-sdk/platinum/platinum-sdk', 
  selector: buildParameter('sdk_to_package'), 
  target: 'artifacts'
)
```